# load chromedriver in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium, web-applications, automated-tests

I'm running a spring boot application and I'm trying to get the chromedriver not load from my local directory but rather from the project resources folder. I have my chromdriver.exe in resources/chromedriver.exe but I'm not sure how can I load it.

I tried this didn't work. Tried filepath to be "resources/chromedriver.exe" didn't work as well

```
  String filePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("resources/chromedriver.exe").getFile();
            System.out.println(filePath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring, you could try this:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;



Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("chromedriver.exe");
String filePath = resource.getFile().getPath();

System.out.println(filePath);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class GettingStarted {
  @Test
  public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException {
    // Optional. If not specified, WebDriver searches the PATH for chromedriver.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
    searchBox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

For example in Windows if chromedriver.exe is in C:/chromium use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromium\\chromedriver.exe");
```